# Bootstrap navbar not active in higher pixel ratio mobile device

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

Suppose I have two mobile device. One's pixel ratio is higher than the other. Suppose higher pixel ratio is a iPhone. Now what the problem is bootstrap navbar is active for the lower dense pixel's phone but not the iPhone which has higher pixel ratio. I have look into the bootstrap class. There I have found that navbar will activate when the device pixel is max 768px and min 767px. To activate the navbar in iPhone i have increase the activation threshold value.

I wrote a custom css file that was overridden the activation threshold value but it did not work for me as there were many bootstrap features not working because of interdependency.

To make the thing works I have to change bootstrap class manually. I've change 768 and 767 value with 990 or something like that, which is median or md in bootstrap. My number might be wrong but you get my point :).

Is there any better way to active navbar in mobile device.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have this view port meta tag? This might help

```
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
```

Comment: is this works only with HTML 5? Because I am using HTML 4.01.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, you can't detect with certitude that a device is a mobile, so media queries are still the way to go.